# What should I learn to become a software project manager?

Tags: software-development, scrum-master, task-management, work-breakdown-structure, sprint-planning

I am a newbie mediocre developer/freelancer working with Angular-NodeJS/MongoDB projects.

What I want to do is create a team and work on bigger and better projects, but my problem is that I don't know how to break the project down into the task/sprints and dividing them between other Front/Back-end developers?

I don't even know how to exactly separate MVC parts of the project?

But I'm here to know, what is the concept/subject that I am looking for? (What I mean is, when searching, what keywords to use?)

And also I want to know if there are any good free videos/books to learn it?

Comment: How you break down the project into WBS is generally going to be found in any guidance on developing a WBS but a great deal will depend on where you fall between waterfall and agile.   "any good/free" is intrinsically subjective and a shopping question.  While I'm very sympathetic to the desire, I'm concerned that this question falls in the [Let's go shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) anti-pattern. I think it can be fixed - can you break out specific questions that you need help researching?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Thank you for remark. What I am looking for is to find a road map/big picture of software project management and a good starting point(free video course like what there are on coursera,etc/book) to learn in a practical manner.

Comment: That is, unfortunately, a shopping question.

Comment: I also found this specialization tha helped me to learn and understand more about how to break down projects to specific tasks: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/software-design-architecture

Answer (score 1):

I am a software project manager. When I started my journey in project management career, I took this course in course. It was really helpful to build the foundation for Sprints, dividing the work etc: "Software Processes and Agile Practices". Additionally you can search on keywords: Agile planning, Scrum Master, Software process.

Some tools to learn that help in planning out the work : Microsoft Project, RALLY.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that Project Management is a skill that one is born with, and can improve with studying and experience.

If you haven't a clue where to start, I'd be worried that you're going to become a newbie mediocre project manager.

But, if you feel you have the Project Management skills; you "feel" you know how to get things done, then go ahead and good luck. 
<sup>If you're not sure, you can read about my ideas about Project Management on [my blog - *the End Game*.](https://blog.expertpjm.com/)</sup>

If you're sure that Project Management is your next career, then start by [Googling "intro to project management"](https://www.google.com/search?q=intro%20to%20project%20management) and see which articles and blogs make sense to you.

On the [video tab](https://www.google.com/search?q=intro%20to%20project%20management&tbm=vid) you will find almost a million videos on the subject.

You can then narrow your searches to *intro to scrum* or *intro to agile* or whatever techniques you decide you want to use.

Good luck!